# 'does not provide an export named 'createRouter'' vue 3, vite and vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3, vue-router4, vite

I just started using vite with vue.

When I'm trying to use vue-router I get the error:

> SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/vue-router/dist/vue-router.esm.js?v=4830dca4' does not provide an export named 'createRouter

My router/index.js looks like this:

```
import {
 createWebHistory,
 createRouter
} from "vue-router";

import Services from "../views/Services.vue";
import Customers from "../views/Customers.vue";

const history = createWebHistory();
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    component: Services
  },
  {
    path: "/customers",
    component: Customers
  },
];
const router = createRouter({
  history,
  routes
});
export default router;
```

My main.js looks like this:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import './index.css'
import router from './router'

createApp(App).use(router).mount('#app')
```

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
 "name": "frontend",
 "version": "0.0.0",
 "scripts": {
 "dev": "vite",
 "build": "vite build"
},
 "dependencies": {
 "vue": "^3.0.5",
 "vue-router": "^3.4.9"
},
 "devDependencies": {
 "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^1.0.4",
 "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.5",
 "autoprefixer": "^10.2.3",
 "postcss": "^8.2.4",
 "tailwindcss": "^2.0.2",
 "vite": "^2.0.0-beta.12"
 }
}
```

Anyone knows how to export the route?

Comment: Use `import VueRouter from "vue-router"`
and when defining use `const router = new VueRouter({ your code})`

Comment: @YashMaheshwari this syntax is for vue 2 with vue router 3

Comment: no worries, you could get that when you see that he's using  vite which works only with vue 3

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should uninstall the current vue-router module and reinstall the latest (version 4) one which is compatible with Vue 3 by running :

```
npm uninstall vue-router
```

then

```
npm install vue-router@next -S
```

Comment: The new portal: https://next.router.vuejs.org/installation.html

Comment: `4.0.6` worked fine for me with `vue@^3.0.5`

Comment: NOTE: If you're running Vite you'll have to shut it down and restart it before this change takes effect. This did solve my problem.

Comment: @Roga do you mean quitting server and restarting again ?

Answer (score 24):

if you check inside the file `'/node_modules/.vite/vue-router/dist/vue-router.esm.js?v=4830dca4'`

there is no `export default` syntax. only named `export {}`

so instead import default, use named import.

```js
// don't
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

// do
import { createRouter, createWebHashHistory } from 'vue-router'
```

Comment: This is the answer if you're referencing:
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#javascript

Comment: I had this issue in `App.vue` and this answer solve my issue.

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth I ran into this same issue while using vue-router@4. I was using yarn instead of npm. Switching to npm fixed the issue. I'm not sure if the problem was yarn or if a fresh install was all that was needed.

Comment: Me too. I have `vue-router@4` and doing it with `yarn`. From your comment, I tried just deleting `node_modules` and reinstalling with `yarn` again and worked!

Answer (score 3):

if you update `vue-router` from v3.x to v4.x under your vite project，plz clear the deps cache

> vite --force

offical docs: https://vitejs.dev/guide/dep-pre-bundling.html#caching

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy solution if exported module actually exports only methods, but you still want to import all of them as an object.

```
// if this does not work
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

// try this
import * as VueRouter from 'vue-router';
```

This usually happens when you import compiled JS into TS.
Same solution works with `underscore` or `lodash`

Answer (score 1):

Don't import like this in **vue3** it will not work

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
```

Import Like this it will work

```
import * as VueRouter from 'vue-router';
```

or Import Specific Then do like this

```
import { createRouter, createWebHashHistory } from 'vue-router'
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to close your app than re open again, I fix this issue